# BakcPack Crud Columns does not show full text, instead they show [...]

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a BP column that is not showing all the text completely, instead it shows **[...]** which is annoying.

Can you tell me how I can solve this?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is truncated by default, to make columns a reasonable width. You can change the limit of a column by specifying “limit” on it (eg. ->limit(999)).

Comment: Thanks a lot, simple as that :D